# How to get the particular values from response using python

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to get the values from JSON which is nested.

```
response = {
   "Instance":[
      {
      "id":"id-1",
      "Tags":[],
      },
      {
      "id":"id-2",
      "Tags":[],
      },
      {
      "id":"id-3",
      "Tags":[
         {
            "Key":"test",
            "Value":"test"
         }
      ],
      }
      ]
}
```

and the python code i tried is

```
     if response["Instance"]:
        print("1-->",response["Instance"])
        for identifier in response["Instance"]:
            print("2-->", identifier)
            if identifier["id"]:
                print("3-->", identifier["id"])
                if identifier["Tags"]:   #ERROR Thrown here as 'Tags' in exception
                    print("4-->", identifier["Tags"])
                    for tag in identifier["Tags"]:
                        print("5-->", identifier["Tags"])
                        if tag['Key'] == 'test' and tag['Value'] == 'test':
                            print("6--> test present ")
```

I am trying to parse through all ids and get the tags that contain the test key. But getting error in 3rd loop when tags has some values. Error in exception is just telling 'Tags'
How can I modify the code?

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: seems like a small recursive function may help you here

Comment: Please share the traceback and the expected output

Comment: expected to get keys in tag and assign to one variable

Comment: @Anwarvic not based on the JSON that we can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing for the presence of the key `"Tags"` in the `identifier` dict as follows:

```
if identifier["Tags"]:
    # iterate over identifier["Tags"]
```

If `"Tags"` is not present in the `identifier` dict, this will result in:

```
KeyError: 'Tags'
```

Instead, you should use:

```
if "Tags" in identifier:
    # iterate over identifier["Tags"]
```

Comment: Solved it thanks!!